# error in Dundas Dashboard not working

Tags: dashboard, dundas

I just installed Dundas dashboard 4.0.2 and it installed successfully. However when I try to open the program, the webpage shows me error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>   Compilation Error
>   Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS0009: Metadata file 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Services\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.Services.dll' could not be opened -- 'An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. '
>
> Source Error:
>
> {No relevant source lines]
>
> Source File:    Line: 0

Answer (score 0):

Looks identical to the error message in the following link:
http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/silverlight/vs-extensions/silverlight-demo-error.aspx

Based on that, it would seem like some prerequisite was not installed. Please post if the solution proposed there resolves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i had the same problem not to long ago. I resolved it by uninstalling the latest release of Microsoft Silverlight and installing version 4 of it. Solved my problem instantly. There does seem to be an issue regarding the new version of Silverligh and Windows.

Comment: Since the message says "Server Error", I don't think it could be related to the Silverlight installation.

Comment: @RobSiklos I don't claim to know the answer, but the error suggests it attempted to `load a program` but doesn't specify which (sounds like Microsoft to me).  That program could be Silverlight.  There's another answer here so far that suggests it may be Silverlight as well.

Comment: @coge.soft: When the web page shows a compiler error, that means ASP.NET is having a problem with dynamic compilation.  That, plus the fact that the path to the DLL in the description is in the GAC, tells very clearly that this is unrelated to Silverlight.  Silverlight never, ever uses the GAC.

Comment: With the new version of Dundas it has resolved. also when installing on Windows server 2008 R2 also install IIS6 tools. Silverlight was just a small issue but as far as my testing has gone no more issues was found. And another thing you will have to do when installing new version of of Dundas is to re-install .netFramework 4. this will also solve any other problems as @RobSiklos has mentioned

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend re-installing the .NET 4.0 framework on the server.

After doing this, check IIS and make sure the application pool which is running Dundas Dashboard is set up to use ASP.NET 4.0 (not 2.0).